# How do I check if GEARS is installed, using javascript?

Tags: javascript, gears

Is it windows.gears != undefined or something???

I just want to use javascript to return true or false if the person has google Gears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Detecting and Installing Gears](http://code.google.com/apis/gears/design.html#detecting) although this requires gears_init.js. Maybe the [source](http://code.google.com/apis/gears/gears_init.js) might give you a hint. It starts out like this, followed by some browser specific 
checks.

```
(function() {
  // We are already defined. Hooray!
  if (window.google && google.gears) {
    return;
  }
```